# Encoding data for imputation and then decoding

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn

I am in python and I have data like the following structure with mixed categorical and numeric

```
subject_id hour_measure         urinecolor   blood pressure                  
3          1.00                 red         
           1.15                             high
4          2.00              yellow          low
```

I want to impute it using hot deck imputation but I found that I should encode it to numeric then make an imputation

```
  from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
    enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
   df= pd.read_csv('path')
    enc.fit(df)
    enc.transform(df)
```

when I try to make encode, it asking me to fill in missing values first, so how can I deal with missing values when making encoding? When I encode the categorical data, the imputation will generate values for missing values and how can I reverse it to the original data after imputation?
please, anyone, help me with this issue?

Comment: What type is `df`; is it a `dict`? If I understand your question, the class `OneHotEncoder` requires no 'missing' elements in the datasource, I assume this to be null values.

Comment: df is a dataframe from csv file

Comment: update it , ok , as you say i should put null to every empty cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to use a scikit-learn pipeline:

```py
import numpy as np

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

X = np.array(
    [['cat1', 'cat1'],
     ['cat2', np.nan],
     [np.nan, 'cat2']],
    dtype=object
)

encoder = make_pipeline(
    SimpleImputer(strategy="constant", fill_value="missing"),
    OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
)
print(encoder.fit_transform(X))
print(encoder[-1].categories_)
```

```
[[1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]]
[array(['cat1', 'cat2', 'missing'], dtype=object), array(['cat1', 'cat2', 'missing'], dtype=object)]
```

Here the missing values are represented by some `np.nan` values. They are first replaced by the string `'missing'`. Then, each category will become a column. Therefore the "missing" information will be represented by a column after the encoding.

You probably don't want to remove this information from your data. If you want you can remove the corresponding columns.

Comment: thank you for your reply . in my case i  deal with CSV file and i want only make encode categorical data in order to be able to make imputing for all data base. your solution works , but it convert all data to 0 and 1 which will be difficult in imputing . furthermore i want to know to to decode these categorical columns after imputing

Comment: To deal with CSV, you will use `pandas.read_csv`. You can select the specific column using the `ColumnTransformer` from scikit-learn (refer to this example: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-compose-plot-column-transformer-mixed-types-py) and use the encoder pipeline on these specific columns. `encoder.inverse_transform(X_encoded)` will convert back the data in the original space

Comment: the idea that i make encoding to make further imputation ? i hope i could find method that make imputation using KNN or hot deck imputation without encoding it ...

Comment: In scikit-learn 0.22 you have a `KNNImputer` and a `IterativeImputer` (imputer which uses a model to predict missing data based on a subset of feature)

Comment: can you give me more explanation to how to implement it

Comment: Replace the `SimpleImputer` by a `KNNImputer`. You can import it `from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer`: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html

Comment: @glemaitre How to use `Iterative Imputer` but to have the `fill_value` part? `Iterative Imputer` doesn't have `fill_value` parameter. My dataset has multiple feature, hence I used Iterative Imputer.

Comment: The point of the `IterativeImputer` is to learn the value to fill and thus it does allow for providing a `fill_value` paraemter.